# How do you say “What is the distance from the neck to the top of the hem?” in German?

Tags: translation

I am struggling with “What is the ***distance*** from the neck to the ***top*** of the hem?”.

Comment: Hi Gergerger! Is your question specific to that context?  Did you look up the word distance in a dictionary? If yes, what problems remain? Answers to these questions will help us help you better. If you can just look it up in the dictionary, the question is off-topic here, though.

Comment: To say specific things like this in a foreign language is always a struggle, even native speakers will have trouble using the right terms and being specific enough. For example the neck is a round structure, which point of the neck is meant here? I would always use a sketch like you did in your other question, mark the line e.g. with a letter and call it "Abstand A" instead of trying to describe it which would most likely introduce unneeded ambiguity.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to say, because I don't see what _neck_ means in this context. It could be _Wieviel Platz bleibt zwischen Halsansatz und der Oberkante des Saums?_

Answer (score 1):

"Länge" is the best use here. Entfernung, Strecke and Weg are used typically for greater distances.

The top of the hem would be referred to as "Die Oberseite des Saums". So the correct translation would be "Was ist die Länge vom Hals bis zur Oberseite des Saums?"

Depending on the context (i. e. you purely speak of a piece of clothing, not the measurements of a person) you could also ask "Was ist die Länge vom Kragen bis zur Oberseite des Saums?" with "Kragen" meaning collar.

Comment: You would rather say *Oberkante* instead of *Oberseite*.

Comment: I think, "Abstand" would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

In principle @Lilium is correct, but tailoring has its own specific vocabulary in German. It is quite conceivable that for exactly this measurement there is a certain word (which i wouldn't know).

Not being a tailor myself i don't know if this is the case and a quick search with duckduckgo.com didn't turn out any conclusive results (perhaps because my search parameters where fittingly ill-fitted).

I will ask a learned tailor later in the day and edit her answer in here.